# How do i vertically center a div inside a div which height varies due to a img inside of it?

Tags: html, css

I have this unfinished example code block:

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 100%; float:left;">
  <img style="max-width:1920px; width:100%; display:block;position:relative; float: left;">
  <div width:400px; ><p>Text and more Text<p></div>
</div>
```

I want the text div to always be in the vertical middle of the picture/parent div and that it has a `margin-right` of like `10%;` since the picture height will change due to the window size i want the text box to always be in the vertical middle of the image.

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle of this?

Comment: solved and closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **CSS Positioning**, and apply `position: absolute`.

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.box-holder {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="box-holder">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
  <p>Text and more Text</p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @ClemensSchwake What happened? Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with `position`.

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

p {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #eee;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-style: 18px;
}

.pictureCaption {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  top: calc(50% - 38px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1462834026679-7c03bf571a67?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=791&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=">
  <p class="pictureCaption">This is some text about this picture.</p>
</div>
```